# Output of select query in where clause not working

Tags: mysql

Update table set Style='new' where id=(SELECT MAX(id) From table);
This is my query. But not working in mysql. 
Error shows: You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of the subquery in a session variable, like so:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxID 
FROM table
;

UPDATE table 
SET Style='new' 
WHERE id=@maxID
;
```

Note that the operation is no longer "atomic"; depending on the activity going on, it is potentially possible for that MAX(id) to change between the SELECT and the UPDATE.

Another possibility is:

```
UPDATE table
SET Style = 'new'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

But I tend to (for no particular reason) be averse to such queries.

Comment: @ArindomChanda you should mark this as the answer then